# I want to compare two json , one from response , one in DB

Tags: sql, node.js, json, testing, automation

```
let body = response.body; // json after hitting the api using automation

 con.query("Select * FROM accounts WHERE name= '"+(Response.name+"'"), (err,rows,fields) => {            
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Fetch Query done successfully for accounts_master tables');

      var string=JSON.stringify(rows);
      console.log("STRING",string);
      var json = JSON.parse(string); //json i need to compare with above.
      console.log("NAMEEEE",json);
```

Output:-

```
{
    id: 11,
    name: 'manav',
    description: 'hellllllo',
    owner: 11,
}
```

I will get output like this in both json , instead of comparing key-values one by one i want to compare the whole output json with DB(which i fetching from DB)
Please , tell me for the same.

Comment: What is the goal? Does it have to be equal OR do you want to see differences?

Comment: if it's not equal ,then i want to make testcase fail
else pass

Comment: Okay check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To check wether 2 objects are fully equal you can compare them as strings.
Do it like so:

```js
// converts anyting to
function objToString(o) {
   // some safety..
   if(typeof o === 'string') {
       return o
   }
   return JSON.stringify(o)
}

// tests whetere 2 objects are equal
function isEqual(o1, o2) {
   return objToString(o1) === objToString(o2)
}

var obj1 = {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2'
}

var obj2 = {
   key1: 'value1',
   key2: 'value2'
}

var obj3 = {
   key1: 'othervalue',
   key2: 'value2'
}

console.log(isEqual(obj1, obj2)) // => true
console.log(isEqual(obj1, obj3)) // => false
console.log(isEqual(obj2, obj3)) // => false
```